# to form a new symbol using list items

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

say I have two lists in lisp

```lisp
(setq a '(p q))
(setq b '(1 2))

(car a) is p
(car b) is 1
```

now I want to define a symbol '(test p 1) but if I use below

```lisp
(setq c '(test (car a) (car b)))
```

I get '(test (car a) (car b))
it is understandable, but I just want to know how can I substitute those (car a) to p and (car b) to 1 and form a new symbol of '(test p 1)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, `setq` should not be used on unbound variables. You can use `setq` on established variables. Also for global variables you should use `*earmuffs*`.

```
(defparameter *a* '(p q))
(defparameter *b* '(1 2))
(car *a*) ; ==> p
(car *b*) ; ==> 1
```

The quote will use the quotes structure as data. That means everything `expr` where you write `'expr` will never be evaluated beyond taking the data verbatim. New lists are created with `cons`. eg.

```
;; creates/updates binding *x* to point at the newly created list (test p 1)
(defparameter *c* (cons 'test 
                        (cons (car *a*) 
                              (cons (car *b*) 
                                    '()))))
```

`cons` is the primitive, but CL has several other ways to create lists. eg. the same with the function `list`:

```
;; creates/updates binding *x* to point at the newly created list (test p 1)
(defparameter *c* (list 'test (car *a*) (car *b*)))
```

The second the structure becomes more complex using `quasiquote`/`unquote`/`unquote-splice` is a lot easier.

```
;; creates/updates binding *x* to point at the newly created list (test p 1)
(defparameter *c* `(test ,(car *a*) ,(car *b*)))

;; more complex example
(defmacro my-let ((&rest bindings) &body body)
  `((lambda ,(mapcar #'car bindings)
      ,@body)
    ,(mapcar #'cadr bindings)))

(macroexpand-1 '(my-let ((a 10) (b 20)) (print "hello") (+ (* a a) (* b b))))
; ==> ((lambda (a b) 
;       (print "hello") 
;       (+ (* a a) (* b b)))
;      (10 20))
```

Note that this is just sugar for the identical structure made with `cons`, `list`, and `append`. It might be optimized for minimal memory use so will share structure. eg.  `` `(,x b c) `` in a procedure will do `(cons x '(b c))` which means if you create two versions their `cdr` will be `eq` and you should refrain from mutating these parts.

Comment: Thank you Sylwester for the detailed explanation, but I want this list is a symbol so that it can pass the symbolp test (return true). is there a way?

Comment: @B.Hong You mean you want to define a **binding**. A symbol is `'test` while `test` is a binding. Isn't that what I do with ``(defparameter *c* `(test ,(car *a*) ,(car *b*)))``. If you write `*c*` afterwards you get `(test p 1)`. Are you suggesting you want a symbol with the text `(test p 1)`? Eg. the same as evaluating `'|(test p 1)|`?

Comment: Thank you Sylwester, yes, I didn't describe it well, as I'm a student and very new to lisp, and trying this to solve an assignment

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make a list the function you want is `list`:

```
(list 'test (car a) (car b))`
```

Will be the list `(test p 1)`.

Note that the purpose of `quote` (abbreviated `'`, so `'(x)` is identical to `(quote (x))`) is simply to tell the evaluator that what follows is literal data, not code. So, in `(list 'test ...)`, which is the same as `(list (quote test) ...)` then `quote` tells the evaluator that `test` is being used as a literal datum, rather than as the name of a binding, and similarly `'(p q)` means 'this is a literal list with elements `p` and `q`', while `(p q)` means 'this is a form for evaluation, whose meaning depends on what `p` is')

Comment: Thank you tfb for the help, the problem is I need that (test p 1) is a symbol. (to pass symbolp test) so or if you can help me to convert this list to symbol?

Comment: @B.Hong I think you need to be more clear about what you want: do you want a symbol whose name is the string `"(test p 1)"`?  Really?  If you do this seems very like some confusion.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you tfb, yes, I didn't describe it well, as I'm a student and very new to lisp, and trying this to solve an assignment

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer from tfb, you can write

```
`(test ,(car a) ,(car b)
```

This is strictly the same of

```
(list 'test (car a) (car b)
```